# How to solve this binary bomb?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, x86-64

I was having trouble with this phase in the binary bomb lab. So far I believe that the answer has to get to be a string less than 29 characters (as seen in +24) and that I have to somehow increment %ebx to 5 before it is allowed to be defused.
My question is how do i know where to look for the answer and what are the steps needed to get there?

```
   0x00000000004010f6 <+0>: push   %r13
   0x00000000004010f8 <+2>: push   %r12
   0x00000000004010fa <+4>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004010fb <+5>: push   %rbx
   0x00000000004010fc <+6>: sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x0000000000401100 <+10>:    mov    %rdi,%r13
   0x0000000000401103 <+13>:    callq  0x4012b1 <string_length> //x/s showed that 0x4012b1 was "\200?" 
   0x0000000000401108 <+18>:    mov    %eax,%r12d //r12d = length of input
   0x000000000040110b <+21>:    lea    -0x1(%rax),%eax
   0x000000000040110e <+24>:    cmp    $0x1d,%eax //refrains from lengths > 30
   0x0000000000401111 <+27>:    jbe    0x401118 <phase_6+34>
   0x0000000000401113 <+29>:    callq  0x40152f <detonate_bomb>
   0x0000000000401118 <+34>:    test   %r12d,%r12d
   0x000000000040111b <+37>:    jle    0x40113d <phase_6+71>
   0x000000000040111d <+39>:    mov    $0x0,%ebx
   0x0000000000401122 <+44>:    movzbl 0x0(%r13,%rbx,1),%eax
   0x0000000000401128 <+50>:    sub    $0x30,%eax
   0x000000000040112b <+53>:    cmp    $0x1,%al //last 4 bits < 1
   0x000000000040112d <+55>:    jbe    0x401134 <phase_6+62>
=> 0x000000000040112f <+57>:    callq  0x40152f <detonate_bomb>
   0x0000000000401134 <+62>:    add    $0x1,%rbx /
   0x0000000000401138 <+66>:    cmp    %ebx,%r12d
   0x000000000040113b <+69>:    jg     0x401122 <phase_6+44>
   0x000000000040113d <+71>:    mov    $0x0,%ebx //start of a a double for loop? 
   0x0000000000401142 <+76>:    mov    $0x0,%ebp
   0x0000000000401147 <+81>:    mov    $0x604300,%eax //(gdb)x 0x604300    <tnode13>:   ""
   0x000000000040114c <+86>:    movzbl (%rax),%edx 
   0x000000000040114f <+89>:    test   %dl,%dl
   0x0000000000401151 <+91>:    je     0x40116d <phase_6+119>
   0x0000000000401153 <+93>:    movslq %ebx,%rax
   0x0000000000401156 <+96>:    cmp    0x402506(%rax),%dl // x 0x402506 = "eaeafc" 
   0x000000000040115c <+102>:   je     0x401163 <phase_6+109>
   0x000000000040115e <+104>:   callq  0x40152f <detonate_bomb>
   0x0000000000401163 <+109>:   add    $0x1,%ebx //incrementing counter 
   0x0000000000401166 <+112>:   mov    $0x604300,%eax
   0x000000000040116b <+117>:   jmp    0x40118d <phase_6+151>
   0x000000000040116d <+119>:   movslq %ebp,%rdx //%rdx = 0
   0x0000000000401170 <+122>:   movzbl 0x0(%r13,%rdx,1),%edx
   0x0000000000401176 <+128>:   cmp    $0x30,%dl
   0x0000000000401179 <+131>:   jne    0x401181 <phase_6+139>
   0x000000000040117b <+133>:   mov    0x8(%rax),%rax
   0x000000000040117f <+137>:   jmp    0x40118a <phase_6+148>
   0x0000000000401181 <+139>:   cmp    $0x31,%dl
   0x0000000000401184 <+142>:   jne    0x40118a <phase_6+148>
   0x0000000000401186 <+144>:   mov    0x10(%rax),%rax
   0x000000000040118a <+148>:   add    $0x1,%ebp //increment %ebp
   0x000000000040118d <+151>:   cmp    $0x5,%ebx
   0x0000000000401190 <+154>:   jg     0x401197 <phase_6+161>
   0x0000000000401192 <+156>:   cmp    %r12d,%ebp //comparing 
   0x0000000000401195 <+159>:   jl     0x40114c <phase_6+86>
   0x0000000000401197 <+161>:   cmp    $0x5,%ebx
   0x000000000040119a <+164>:   jne    0x4011a2 <phase_6+172>
   0x000000000040119c <+166>:   cmpb   $0x63,(%rax)
   0x000000000040119f <+169>:   nop
   0x00000000004011a0 <+170>:   je     0x4011a7 <phase_6+177> //if %rax == 99 jump
   0x00000000004011a2 <+172>:   callq  0x40152f <detonate_bomb>
   0x00000000004011a7 <+177>:   add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x00000000004011ab <+181>:   pop    %rbx
   0x00000000004011ac <+182>:   pop    %rbp
   0x00000000004011ad <+183>:   pop    %r12
   0x00000000004011af <+185>:   pop    %r13
   0x00000000004011b1 <+187>:   retq
```

Comment: Take it to the Bomb Squad.

Comment: Add comments to the code, or notes somewhere, with everything you've figured out so far about what this function is doing, and what constraints that places on the input.  The binary bomb challenge was kinda fun the first time, but starting from scratch on every bomb question on SO gets old fast.  It's a lot easier for others to see if the comments look sensible than to solve it from near-scratch for you.

Comment: Also, a disassembler like Agner Fog's `objconv` will place branch-target labels in the output code, making it easier to see find the targets of branches.  (And it disassembles in NASM syntax, rather than the less-popular AT&T.)

Answer (score 2):

The code does a `jbe` after comparing with 29, so the condition is actually that the string length must be less than *or equal* to 29.

I don't see anything that makes me think `ebx` = 5 would help.  It's an array index for a load from the string.  It's probably in a loop, so the condition has to be true for all the characters.  I stopped reading the code around there.

I'd highly recommend [`objconv`](http://www.agner.org/optimize/).  I found it really helpful when I did a binary bomb recently, since it saved the manual grunt-work of writing in the branch targets by hand (or of keeping in your head which branch goes where).